# Reduce some of the word size in <h1> tag

Tags: html, header, tags

```
<h1>Zone <h3>&#9679;</h3> Floor <h3>&#9679;</h3> Level</h1>
```

Hi, I would like to minimize the size of a circle dot to h3 tag, but it's not working, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your HTML is completely invalid and the browser needs to fix it, but it can't figure out what you could possibly have in mind. This is what Firefox composes:

[image: DOM pane]

You should really switch to CSS:

```
<h1>Zone <span>&#9679;</span> Floor <span>&#9679;</span> Level</h1>
```

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 14pt;
}
h1 span {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

Ignoring the semantics of HTML tags and using them just by their default styling was already bad in the late 1990s.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to reduce the size of the HTML entity dot? Simple, do this. It'll reduce the font size from the browser default of 12px to .8em.

```
h3 {
  font-size:.8em;
}
```

or if you want to reduce everything where that `h1` is wrapped inside of, do this.

```
h1 {
  font-size:.8em;
}
```

Comment: but my code will auto nextline if h3 tag is inside h1

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I was simply answering your question of how to reduce the word size of the h1 tag. Do you want them to display as a list?

Comment: I gv u an image link

Comment: My situtation https://www.dropbox.com/s/zlhgi6v8qorf8t9/Screenshot%20from%202017-04-18%2000-12-31.png?dl=0

Comment: The result I need is horizontal but it came out vertical

Answer (score 0):

try making the h1 size in css diffrent...

```
h1 {
    font-size: 14pt;
}
```

or

```
h1 {
    font-size: 8em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the WordPress theme doesn't support certain tags, Here I've added latest tags which most of WordPress theme support. I have also the same problem I've to resolve this problem by this CSS HTML tags.

If all the above tags which listed here won't work on your web page for your version. Then you should try this one code.

```
.entry h3 {
font-size: 1.45em;
```

}

Sometimes this tag is useful for you.